# Read image path from pandas data frame and arrange them based on filename

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, image

I have a data frame with the image paths in first column. As shown here:
[input dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDhWI.png)

The filename of imagecontains IDs(ImageID) and type of image (Topo). I want to generate output data frame such as, it generates different columns of different Topos. So for one Image ID I get six columns of Topos.
Output as shown here:
[Output dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6fSP.png)

The number of Topos can be different, it can run from 4 to 27. So the numbers of output columns can be different.

Answer (score 1):

#### First we have to extract the list of Topos:

```py
list_of_topos = list(pd.DataFrame([x.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0] for x in df['Image ID'].tolist()])[0].unique())
```

Here we created a series of values after splitting the **Image ID** by "_" and ".", and take a list of unique values

#### Then we create the new columns as follow:

```py
df[list_of_topos] = None
```

#### The final step is to assign the values for each row columns:

```py
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    extention = "." + row['Image'].split(".")[-1]
    row[list_of_topos] = ["_".join(row['Image'].split("_")[:-1]) + x + extention for x in list_of_topos]
```

> Please note that this solution is supposing that all data is in the same structure as in your question